# What are the differences between "ignore" and "neglect"?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I came across the following statement:

People have either **ignored** or **neglected** these effects because...

I think there must be some subtle differences between the two **bold** words.
Anyone could point out it? You are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one

> ignores *something*

one is *actively* not paying any attention, on purpose

> She *ignored* his advances until he left her alone.
>   The referee *ignored* the crowd's screaming for a penalty.

When one

> neglects *something*

one may have forgotten about, or not been aware of a critical situation for *something* one was supposed to take care of or oversee

> Their electricity bill was very high since they *neglected* to turn off the lights.
>   The plant was never watered and died of *neglect*.

Your example sentence would be more correct as

> People *have* either ignored or neglected...

Answer (score 1):

> 1. [*ignore*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ignore)
>      to refrain from noticing or recognizing
> 2. [*neglect*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/neglect)
>      to pay no attention or too little attention to; disregard or slight

However, neglect also has a meaning that implies a sense of responsibility:

> [[3.]](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/neglect) to be remiss in the care or treatment of

So, the word *ignore* suggests that the people are aware of the effects, but do not give it much thought or do anything about it. It is possible that they are not obligated to take any action. On the other hand, using the word *neglect*, the author suggests that the people have a responsibility *to do* something about these effects, like remedy them, record them, report them, etc.

---

Note, there is a matter of "People has". As I understand it, the word *people* is plural. So I think it should be *People have*, unless there is a good reason it should be otherwise that has been omitted.

Comment: @ probablyme, Thanks a lot, your answer is as good as the accepted one. I accepted @Peter's answer because he provided more examples.